# Replace text of current paragraph in MS word Office.js add-in

Tags: ms-word, office-js

In a Word add-in, I'm trying to:

1. receive `documentSelectionChanged` events,
2. get the text of the current paragraph, and
3. replace the string `foo` with the string `bar` in the current paragraph.

Everything is working except the last part.  The text of the Word document isn't changing.

This is my code:

```
function updateText() {
  var range, foo_range, par;
  Word.run(function (context) {
    range = context.document.getSelection();
    range.paragraphs.load('items');
    return context.sync()
    .then(function() {
      par = range.paragraphs.items[0];
      console.log(par.text); // THIS WORKS!
      foo_range = par.search('foo');
      foo_range.load('items');
    })
    .then(context.sync)
    .then(function() {
      console.log(foo_range.items[0].text); // THIS WORKS!
      foo_range.items[0].insertText('bar', 'Replace');
      // Here, I am trying all the load options I can think of 
      foo_range.load('items');
      foo_range.items[0].load('text');
      foo_range.load('text');
      range.paragraphs.load('items');
      range.paragraphs.load('text');
      return context.sync();
    });
  });
}
```

Any idea why `foo` doesn't get replaced by `bar` in the Word document?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce. Your code works for me on desktop Office 365.

BTW, none of those `load` calls before the last `context.sync` do anything, and you should delete them. You only need to load a property (and then sync) when you are going to *read* the property after the sync. Since you are only writing to the document, you don't need to load anything.

Comment: Strange, this is the second time that my code works for you but not for me.  Any idea of where the problem might be?  E.g., Mac-specific bug, configuration in manifest, or something else?

Comment: First, see if your code works in [the Script Lab tool](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104380862?src=office&corrid=dff7bec8-77da-4fa7-90a0-a44bb6203209&omexanonuid=05903015-be38-40af-b6c5-af5743f98476&referralurl=https%3a%2f%2fwww.microsoft.com%2fen-us%2fgarage%2fprofiles%2fscript-lab%2f). If not, I would suspect a Mac-specific bug, in which case you should raise an issue on the [office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues).

Comment: Rick, so the problem turned out to be the permissions in my manifest.  I had `ReadAllDocument` but I need `ReadWriteDocument `.  I had forgotten that the manifest had such permissions.